# Visualizing layer using categorized AND graduated styles in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style, rule-based

I have a layer with road segments that come in five different classes and each have a value. I am trying to get a graduated color for the values (say, light blue for low and dark blue for high values) and at the same time make the highways (class 0) thicker than local roads (class 4) etc.

Now, usually I visualize the colors using about 10 classes (quantiles), so I'd end up defining somewhere around 50 rules: road class 1, value 0-100 - road class 1, value 100-500 and so on.

Is there a way to get there any quicker?

Using Version 2.18.10

Comment: What about **duplicating** the layer and having one with categorised style and the other with graduated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are aiming to:

(1) Select `Graduate` and choose "values" for `Columns`.

(2) Set your Color ramp to `Blues`, perhaps

(3) Click on `Symbol: --Change...` button to activate `Symbol selector`

(4) Click on the small Epsilon button (i.e. `Data defined override`) right to `Width`

(5) Enter suitable expression something like: `(5 - "classes") * 2`.  (Probably `2` is too much...)

[image]

Comment: This totally did it! Thanks a lot; this was a great help!

Comment: @ThinWhiteDuke - Don't forget to accept this answer by clicking the green-faded tick on the left-hand side :)